Get only items data of the hovered bars stack in the tooltip ( formatter )
With bar charts in stack configuration we can only have the item informations or the whole axis informations in the tooltip by using trigger param.
Image exemple with trigger=axis
It is not really clear enough so what we would like is show all the items data of the hovered bars stack but not those of the other stacks of the axis
I tried to use both item and axis for trigger params.
I thought that using axis params will help us to manipulate in the tooltip formatter data items to show only those of the hovered stacks.
But I didn't found a way to get hovered stack information / name
So we are looking for a way to get the hovered stack informations in the tooltip formatter to help us formatting tooltip with all items data of the hovered bars stack
I didn't thought any questions on this topic on stack but some things pretty close on github :
https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/15268#issuecomment-2034955282
https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/14774#issuecomment-2036378058

You can use trigger: 'item and the tooltip formatter.
Example:
const data = [
  {1: 120, 2: 220, 3: 150, 4: 620}, 
  {1: 132, 2: 182, 3: 232, 4: 732}, 
  {1: 101, 2: 191, 3: 201, 4: 701},
  {1: 134, 2: 234, 3: 154, 4: 734},
  {1: 90, 2: 290, 3: 190, 4: 1090},
  {1: 230, 2: 330, 3: 330, 4: 1130},
  {1: 210, 2: 310, 3: 410, 4: 1120}
];

option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item',
    formatter: showStack
  },
  xAxis: [
    {
      type: 'category',
      data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    }
  ],
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      name: '1',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'Ad',
      data: data.map(item => item[1])
    },
    {
      name: '2',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'Ad',
      data: data.map(item => item[2])
    },
    {
      name: '3',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'Search Engine',
      data: data.map(item => item[3])
    },
    {
      name: '4',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'Search Engine',
      data: data.map(item => item[4])
    },
  ]
};

function showStack(params) {
  let value1;
  let value2;
  if (params.seriesName === '1' || params.seriesName === '2') {
    value1 = '1: ' + data[params.dataIndex][1];
    value2 = '2: ' + data[params.dataIndex][2];
  } else if (params.seriesName === '3' || params.seriesName === '4') {
    value1 = '3: ' + data[params.dataIndex][3];
    value2 = '4: ' + data[params.dataIndex][4];
  }
  
  return params.name + '<br>' + value1 + '<br>' + value2;
}


It wasn't as simple as in your example, given my code, but the idea is there, thank you very much.
